# How can I make my domain secure, and invisible?

Tags: security, ssl, dns

My problem is that if I type my domain without any slashes, it shows the complete folder and file structure, so we can say it is not really secure. I've managed to encrypt the folders, but not the main domain. In the cPanel I dont't find where can I make it secure, and invisible. Please don't devalue me for this question, I'm new.

Comment: What technology are you using? Since you say cPanel, am I safe to assume it's an Apache/PHP site?

Comment: Probably best to ask this question in the correct Stack Exchange. This one is for programming - your issue is a devops/server question. However, you need to look into directory indexing

Comment: The cPanel i talked about looks like this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndPou9vygHI     Sorry, next time I'm going to post it to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent users from viewing the directory listing, you should select the no indexing option in cpanel. See this link for more information: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/remove-index-listing.

You can also password protect your domain using .htaccess and .htpasswd